# If I delete one of two relationships between two EF entities will the other be deleted?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two entities with a many-to-many relationship, they are `User` and `Test`. The `User` entity has `IList<Test> Tests` and the `Test` entity has `IList<User> Users`.

Ive already got a variable call `myTest` which was gotten earlier with:

```
var myTest = db.Tests.Find(someId);
```

If I want to quickly remove a relationship from some `User` objects and `MyTest` may I do the following?

```
myTest.Users.Clear();
db.SaveChanges();
```

Or must I do something like this?

```
foreach(user in myTest.Users)
{
  user.Tests.Remove(myTest)
}
myTest.Users.Clear();
db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relationships are synced so removing from either side is enough.